# Javascript: setDate(DATE + day) not update month

Tags: javascript

I created this function to increment a date (for a jQuery UI Datepicker):

```
function addDay(date) {
    var moreDay = new Date();
    var decomposed = date.split("-");
    var act = new Date(decomposed[2], decomposed[1], decomposed[0]);
    moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1);
    return moreDay;
}
```

So, it scomposes the date (ex: 12-06-2013 (dd-mm-YYYY)) and put the values into a new Date, after that it addes a day. It works, but the month not change. Example, I changed the function into this:

```
function addDay() {
    var moreDay = new Date();
    var act = new Date(2013, 7, 3);
    moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1);
    alert(moreDay);
}
```

And it returns Jun 4th 2013.. How it's possible?

Comment: in JS, january = zero, not one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do with your function. If you want to take a date and add a day, try with this:

```
function addDay(date) {
    var decomposed = date.split("-"),
        moreDay = new Date(decomposed[2], decomposed[1] - 1, decomposed[0]);
    moreDay.setDate(moreDay.getDate() + 1);
    alert(moreDay);
}
```

Please take note that in common dd-mm-yyyy dates, January is 1, whereas to define a `Date` object January is 0, hence the `- 1`.

This alternative should be faster than `setDate`:

```
moreDay.setTime(moreDay.getTime() + 864e5);
```

Or you could define your `Date` object directly with an added day:

```
moreDay = new Date(decomposed[2], decomposed[1] - 1, +decomposed[0] + 1);
```

Comment: @Macheneso It does *not* add a month. My function does exactly what I stated it does, but I'm not sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 14):

I think I see what's the trouble.

```
function addDay() {
    var moreDay = new Date();
    var act = new Date(2013, 7, 3);
    moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1);
    alert(moreDay);
}
```

> And it returns Jun 4th 2013.. How it's possible?

Some points you must consider:

- The creation of the date `new Date(2013, 7, 3)` does **not** create the date **03/Jul/2013**:

  - Months are **zero-based**, meaning they go from 0 to 11, not 1 to 12.

    - This way, the month `7` actually is **August**.
- The statement `moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1)` **does not make** `moreDay` the date `act` plus one day. Because:

  - `date.getDate()` [returns the **day** of the month](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_setdate.asp) of the `date` variable
  - [`date.setDate(int)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate) sets the *day* of `date` (*just* the day, leaving the year and month intact)
  - What the statement  `moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1)` does then is:

    - Set `moreDay`'s **day** the value of `act`'s day plus one.

In other words, as `moreDay`'s value is `new Date()` (which is the current day - right now **11/Jun/2013** where I live), and `act`'s day is `3`, the statement **evaluation** then really is:

```
Step #1: moreDay.setDate( act.getDate() + 1 );
Step #2: moreDay.setDate( (03/Aug/2013).getDate() + 1 );
Step #3: moreDay.setDate( 03 + 1 );
Step #4: moreDay.setDate( 4 );
Step #5: (11/Jun/2013).setDate( 4 );
Step #6: (04/Jun/2013)
```

Thus ending Jun 4th 2013.

Answer (score 5):

```
moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1);
```

This will only add one day. Why do you expect it to add a month, too?

If you want to add a month also, try this:

```
function addDay() {
    var moreDay = new Date();
    var act = new Date(2013, 7, 3);
    moreDay.setMonth(act.getMonth()+1); // add one month
    moreDay.setDate(act.getDate()+1); // add one day
    alert(moreDay);
}
```

Comment: I want that if I add a day from a date, example if is April 7th 2013 and I add a day, it will be April 8th 2013. So, in that example, Aug 3rd has to be Aug 4th, but it is Jun 4th..

EDIT: Ok, now I saw that I modify only the day and not all the date.. Damn.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
var now = new Date();
        function addDays(date,days) {
            var currentDate = date.getDate();
            date.setDate(currentDate + days);
            alert(date);
        }
    addDays(now,14)
```